# Best way to call Graph API in a Loop

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

We are trying to make some reports using FB Data in which we get the FB ID of the users. For getting the gender and location, we need to call the Graph API https://graph.facebook.com/User_ID in a loop.

This takes lot of time as the number of users are very high. Is there any alternate way to increase the speed of execution.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any alternate way to increase the speed of execution.

There’s multiple ways of getting more data in one request.

Probably the simplest: Giving the API a list of comma-separated IDs, like http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=4,5

Then there’s also [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), where you can put multiple API calls into one HTTP request, which also speeds things up by a lot, since usually the HTTP request is the slowest factor in communicating with the API.

Then there’s FQL, where you can also request data for multiple IDs at once, using `… WHERE id IN(…,…)`, and even the possibility to do “multi queries”.